# Library Document Sync want to remove the files from Computer and want to keep them Sharepoint online

Tags: document-library, document, sync

I wanted to map the SharePoint Library Document to my computer, but I couldn't so I used Sync option to Sync the folder to the Library Document, but now the problem is I have two folders one on my computer and one on the SharePoint online, how can I map the SharePoint folder to my computer instead of using Sync.

Answer (score 0):

While Mapping a Drive to SharePoint Online it fails with below error.

The Mapped Network Drive could not be created because the following error has occurred. 'Access Denied'. Before opening files in this location, you must first add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site and select the option to login Automatically.

Resolution

Open IE -> Go to ‘Internet Options’
Select ‘Security’ tab -> Select ‘Internet’ Zone.
UnCheck the box for ‘Enable Protected Mode’
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepoint_made_easy/archive/2013/03/20/map-network-drive-webdav-with-sharepoint-online-o365.aspx